# Behat My definitions are not loaded

Tags: symfony, behat

I've taken a huge list definition that i've put on my `FeatureContext` That only problem is when i do : `bin/behat -c app/config/behat.yml -dl` they are not showing on the list

Here's my `behat.yml` configuration :

```
default:
    paths:
        features: features
    context:
        parameters:
            class: BundleMyBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true

        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            default_session: sahi
            javascript_session: sahi
            sahi: ~
            browser_name: firefox
            base_url:   http://myapp.dev/
```

The `ContextClass` itslef was generated when I ran `--init` command, and i simply added definitions in it.

What did i miss ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class configuration is completely wrong :)

Use `extensions > Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension > bundle`:

```
default:
    paths:
        features: features
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
            bundle: BundleMyBundle

        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            default_session: sahi
            javascript_session: sahi
            sahi: ~
            browser_name: firefox
            base_url:   http://myapp.dev/
```

Comment: Well the last time i used Behat with my Behat'ch teeshirt on, was a old version without extension. My bad for the misconfiguration ;-) Thx

Comment: Actually, even for old config version, you've made mistake. Context `class` value should be under `context` key, not under `context > parameters` ;)